# Дергается верстка на Retina

Tags: html

Ребята помогите плиз .. Отдал верстку заказчику он в ответ прислал видео https://youtu.be/jiZOtffU4Ss Я подзреваю что это Mac с retina ,браузер safari . Верстка на flex-box , во всех других браузерах оттестил все в порядке. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ответы на Apple:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4157768?start=30&tstart=0

```
Step 1: Delete system windowserver preferences
In the Finder, from the menu bar, select "Go -> Go to Folder..."
Enter: /Library/Preferences/
Delete the file called com.apple.windowserver.plist

Step 2: Delete user windowserver preferences
In the Finder, from the menu bar, select "Go -> Go to Folder..."
Enter: ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/
Delete all files that start with com.apple.windowserver (On my rMBP, there was one file called com.apple.windowserver.12AFB147-95D6-5C70-8F62-C1E4F2BE81BE)

Step 3: Reset the PRAM
(These instructions are from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)
Shut down your Mac.
Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
Turn on the computer.
Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
Release the keys.
```

То есть, проблема в Mac'е заказчика!